# Show/hide ListBox Items on user action

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

My WPF app is using a ListBox to show trace messages of various groups.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=UI, Path=List}" x:Name="listBox">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Name="grid1" >
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="70" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="140" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.Background>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=Color}"/>
                </Grid.Background>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=ItemId}"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Timestamp}"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Path=Message}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Here is the definition of the Items in related ObservableCollection.

```
public class MyModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private uint _itemId;
    private string _timestamp;
    private string _message;
    private string _color;
    private int _group;

    public uint     ItemId   {...}
    public string   Timestamp{...}
    public string   Message  {...}
    public string   Color    {...}
    public int      Group    {...}
    ...
}
```

Now I want to give the user the possibility to select one ore more groups to be shown or hidden at runtime. 
I don't want to just delete the items of the group from the ObservableCollection in order to be able to show them later again.

Can this be somehow managed by the XAML?

**Edit1:**
Based on the hint from **HiMa_D3ViL's** I have enhanced "MyModel" with *Visibility* property and modified my XAML to

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=UI, Path=List}" x:Name="listBox">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Name="grid1" Visibility="{Binding Path=Visibility}">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="70" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="140" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.Background>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=Color}"/>
                </Grid.Background>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=ItemId}"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Timestamp}"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Path=Message}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

It partly works. Meaning the related Entry will be hidden, but it will leave an empty space in the ListBox. See here:

[image]

Comment: Try using CollectionViewSource which provides the ability to filter (through predicate) the bind data on provided condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the size of your collection and the number of times it gets accessed, you could hold this logic in a seperate property getter, that is used as a binding source ONLY

```
public Interface IHidable
{
    bool hidden;
}

public class MyModel : IHidable , ...
{

}

private Collection<MyModel> realCoollection;  //use this for anything else
public Collection<IHidable > viewCollection  //Bind this in your WPF
{
  get {
     Collection<IHidable>  resCollection = new Collection<IHidable>();
     foreach (MyModel item in realCoollection)
     {            
        if (!item.hidden) res.Add((IHidable)item)
     }
     return resCollection;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The collections can get really big, so I assume this might not be the best  solution (from performance and memory consumption point of view)

Comment: Ive been using these kinds of properties for some time now to hold a number of different decorations depending on which control my collection is bound to. This solution is actually a lot less memory and performance hungry than it might seem, as it only holds references to your objects and creating such a list is very cheap compared to the stuff WPF does in the background anyway. Also the number of times the getters is accessed is really not that high usually. ...But I don't know just how big your collection is.

Comment: My collection can contain millions of line easily

Comment: I completely missunderstood what you are trying to do. Simple filtering is actually pretty straight forward. See here: http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-filtering/

Comment: I read the tutorial and this sound really promissing. Initially I misunderstood this feature, because I thought _CollectionViewSource_ just duplicated the list.  The stuff from the tutorial works fine and it filters the cotent when I enter something to the textbox.

Comment: I adopting the same methodology to my project. This results in controlling  if new items that are just added to the list are show or not.  Unfortunatey it does not have an effect on the item that are already existing  in the list. I assume the CollectionViewSource is busy with constantly adding new item, that there is no time left to revalidate the whole list with the existing item. does that make sense???. Any idea how to get around this behaviour?

Comment: Finally I've got it. I simply forgot to refresh :             **CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(listBox.ItemsSource).Refresh();**
@OwlSolo: Thank you very much. Very appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Create a property of type Visibility in your model class and write style for ListBoxItem such as:

```
<Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding Path=YourVisibilityProperty}"/>
 <Style/>
```

now, based on user action it allows you to collapse and visible item but still it remains in your observable collection.

Comment: It did not work for me. But changing my XAMl to `<Grid Name="grid1" Visibility="{Binding Path=Visibility}">` results in empty lines in the ListBox.

Comment: yeah, i got your point if you are doing it with ListBoxItemStyle than only it works perfect as you want and this is perfectly work for me, still you have got issue than will u send me more detail of code.

Comment: Your problem also can be solved by trigger such as:   <Style x:Key="ListBoxtemStyleNoHighlighting" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
       <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsVisible}" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsVisible}" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>